# C++ CLR WCF client - ошибка формата SOAP XML данных

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, wcf, clr

В C++ CLR WCF клиенте на выходе получается формат отличный от аналогичного C# WCF клиента. Вот собственно дампы что они шлют:

**C++ CLR WCF:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
  <h:Email xmlns:h="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  <h:Id xmlns:h="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  <h:PCName xmlns:h="http://tempuri.org/">DESKTOP-62MUR5B</h:PCName>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
  <DataReportRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <FileName>Program1.cs</FileName>
    <InnerException xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GameReport" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_Data i:nil="true"/>
      <a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_Errno>111999</a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_Errno>
      <a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_IsException>false</a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_IsException>
      <a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_Message>c++ test error 1 with errno</a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_Message>
      <a:_x003C_backing_store_x003E_Trace i:nil="true"/>
    </InnerException>
    <Line>52</Line>
    <Method>Main</Method>
  </DataReportRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**C# WCF**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soaap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
  <h:Email xmlns:h="http://tempuri.org/">cs@mail.ru</h:Email>
  <h:Id xmlns:h="http://tempuri.org/">222222222222</h:Id>
  <h:PCName xmlns:h="http://tempuri.org/">DESKTOP-62MUR5B</h:PCName>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
  <DataReportRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <FileName>Program2.cs</FileName>
    <InnerException xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GameReport" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <a:_x003C_Data_x003E_k__BackingField i:nil="true"/>
      <a:_x003C_Errno_x003E_k__BackingField>111999</a:_x003C_Errno_x003E_k__BackingField>
      <a:_x003C_IsException_x003E_k__BackingField>false</a:_x003C_IsException_x003E_k__BackingField>
      <a:_x003C_Message_x003E_k__BackingField>cs test error 1 with errno</a:_x003C_Message_x003E_k__BackingField>
      <a:_x003C_Trace_x003E_k__BackingField i:nil="true"/>
    </InnerException>
    <Line>18</Line>
    <Method>Main</Method>
  </DataReportRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Собственно сервер понимает `C#` клиента, и не понимает `C++ CLR` клиента.
Там получаются пустые значения.
Чем собственно этот формат регулируется ? и как бы его привести к "рабочему" виду?

**P.S.**
В процессе эксперементов выяснилось до кучи, что если использовать в `C++ CLR` классы данных с сеттерами/гетерами, то в выходной xml он пихает имя приватной переменной :) тихий ужас..

вот пример на тех-же данных:

```
<s:Body>
  <DataReportRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <FileName>Program.cs</FileName>
    <InnerException xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GameReport" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <a:__data/>
      <a:__err>111999</a:__err>
      <a:__isexept>false</a:__isexept>
      <a:__msg>test error 1 with errno</a:__msg>
      <a:__trace/>
    </InnerException>
    <Line>52</Line>
    <Method>Main</Method>
  </DataReportRequest>
</s:Body>
```

**C++ Class**

```
[Serializable]
[MessageContract]
public ref class DataReportException
{
public:
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property bool IsException;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property int Errno;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property String ^Message;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property String ^Data;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property String ^Trace;
}
[Serializable]
[MessageContract]
public ref class DataReportRequest
{
public:
    [MessageHeader]
    property String ^Id;
    [MessageHeader]
    property String ^Email;
    [MessageHeader]
    property String ^PCName;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property int Line;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property String ^FileName;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property String ^Method;
    [MessageBodyMember]
    property DataReportException ^InnerException;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в несовместимости выходных данных сериализации между `C++ CLR` и `C#`. Атрибут `[Serializable]` в такой схеме применять не стоит.